# Events for YouTube embed on Mobile Safari, iPhone (callback on stop)

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, safari, youtube

I'm working on this mobile site, where I need to play a YouTube video in Fullscreen. So far, so good. Just a YouTube embed, and voilá.

But! (Yeah, there's always a «but»)

I need to fire an event (namely, a JS function) when the video ends. I figured Safari translated the **YT embed** to a `<video>` tag, so I tried using **HTML5s video events**, but didn't work:

```
$('video').bind('ended', function () {
    alert('Video has ended');
});
```

> *This fine piece of code works when using a `<video>` tag directly, but not when using a YT embed.*

So, any ideas on how can I fire this function when the YT video has finished playing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that it's not setting the ID of the YT embed to 'video'?  If so, see if you have an alternate way of finding the item within the DOM.

Comment: The selector `$('video')` matches every `<video>` tag. It needs a `#` to match by ID.

Comment: In that case, it's possible Apple's got a Safari-specific tag that `$('video')` isn't matching.  There has to be some way to output the source of the page, though.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your YT instance, you can provide a hash that maps events to handlers. Provide a handler for the onStateChange event, and test for the eventType that corresponds to video end ( 0 ).

```
new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
        'onStateChange' : function ( eventType ) { if ( eventType.data == 0 ) { ... } }
    }
} );
```

See the section of YouTube's JavaScript API for [events](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events)